# Matplotlib.pyplot: как развернуть деления по осям Y и X в область графика?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Строю графики с помощью matplotlib.pyplot (код исключительно для примера):

```
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)  
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: какой командой можно развернуть сами штрихи возле меток по обоим осям в область графика (т. е. в область рамки вокруг кривой)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У объекта типа `Axes` есть метод [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

Направление черточек определяет свойство `direction`: `ax.tick_params(direction ='in')`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого объекта можно добраться двумя способами.

1. Функция `pyplot.gca()` возвращает текущий чертёж, на котором рисует `pyplot`

```
plt.gca().tick_params(direction ='in')
plt.plot(x, y)
```

2. Можно создать чертёж явным образом через фигуру:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.tick_params(direction ='in')
ax.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Долго искал, а так все просто оказалось